# Can not register jersey MultiPartFeature

Tags: jersey, jersey-client

I'm trying to create a test case for my Jersey REST application.

I added already in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.25</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm creating my client with:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .register(MoxyJsonFeature.class)
        .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
        .build();
```

But this is failing with an `InstantiationException` on line `.register(MultiPartFeature.class)`. Here is the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide

    at __randomizedtesting.SeedInfo.seed([8269888A1B7E6430]:0)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ConfigurationImpl.createProvider(ConfigurationImpl.java:199)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ConfigurableImpl.register(ConfigurableImpl.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ConfigurableImpl.register(ConfigurableImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ConfigurableImpl$FeatureContextImpl.register(ConfigurableImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ConfigurableImpl$FeatureContextImpl.register(ConfigurableImpl.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature.configure(MultiPartFeature.java:67)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ConfigurableImpl.register(ConfigurableImpl.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ConfigurableImpl.doRegister(ConfigurableImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ConfigurableImpl.register(ConfigurableImpl.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ConfigurableImpl.register(ConfigurableImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.ClientBuilderImpl.register(ClientBuilderImpl.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.ClientBuilderImpl.register(ClientBuilderImpl.java:35)
    at fr.pilato.elasticsearch.crawler.fs.test.integration.AbstractRestITCase.startRestClient(AbstractRestITCase.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.invoke(RandomizedRunner.java:1764)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$6.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:811)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$7.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:827)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.ThreadLeakControl$StatementRunner.run(ThreadLeakControl.java:367)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ConfigurationImpl.createProvider(ConfigurationImpl.java:197)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    ... 24 more
```

I don't understand what I'm missing here. I followed [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart) but I might have missed something.
When I remove the line `.register(MultiPartFeature.class)`, I'm able to run REST tests normally using my client.

Any idea?

Comment: I might know what is happening. Sounds like I have in my classpath and older version of CXF. Checking... Will update my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was caused by another dependency in my project: `org.apache.tika:tika-langdetect:1.14`. tika-langdetect adds apache CXF to the classpath which seems to trouble a bit Jersey.

When excluding CXF from my project, I can see that Jersey is only using "Jersey" classes:

```
  at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature.configure(MultiPartFeature.java:67)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:730)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:648)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.configureMetaProviders(ClientConfig.java:372)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:405)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.access$000(ClientConfig.java:90)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State$3.get(ClientConfig.java:122)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State$3.get(ClientConfig.java:119)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:340)
  - locked <0x1178> (a java.lang.Object)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:733)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getConfiguration(ClientRequest.java:286)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.validateHttpMethodAndEntity(JerseyInvocation.java:135)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:105)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:101)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:437)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:343)
  at fr.pilato.elasticsearch.crawler.fs.test.integration.FsCrawlerRestIT.testUploadFile(FsCrawlerRestIT.java:56)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-1)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

I now need to understand why actually this CXF dependency is confusing Jersey but that's another story :)

EDIT: basically you can't have both CXF and Jersey on the same classpath as they are providing different implementation for the same JaxRS feature.

For my project, I don't need Tika upload/download features, so I can simply exclude Apache CXF from tika dependencies with:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-langdetect</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How do you get around this conflict if the CXF is needed by that dependency? My stuff uses jersey and the dependency uses CXF.

Comment: As I wrote basically you can't have both CXF and Jersey on the same classpath as they are providing different implementation for the same JaxRS feature.

Comment: there isn't a way to do it in maven? I was reading that dependency order mattered, but since it's not a direct dependency on my project I wasn't sure if there was a way to tell the project to only use the implementation I choose. It's not a big deal. I am just going to move that code that is dependant into it's own project.

Comment: Trying to hack the classloader is not a good idea IMHO. Well it's a hack :)

Comment: Yeah, wouldn't want to hack the classloader. lol. but then potentially having any two jaxrs implementations on the classpath can potentially cause the same issues? That seems like bad design to me, but i'm fairly new to jaxrs.
Even perhaps if there was a way to use a config file that tells your project which one to use.

Comment: Yes. That's why for my project I'm excluding the lib I don't want so I don't have conflicts. I don't know how you can solve that